# How to have Spyder open on the 'variable explorer' by default

Tags: ide, spyder

When I open Spyder (4.0.1) the 'Files' tab opens by default, rather than the 'Variable explorer' that's hosted in the same pane.

How do I make Spyder open on the 'Variable explorer' by default instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing:

In the Spyder menu, under View -> Panes, I disabled panes that I didn't need and then arranged the remaining panes so that the variable explorer was by itself.